# How to compare two PIN's are same or not in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, provider

This is my screen, and initially, the text **Set PIN for your Card Ending With XXXX** will be displayed. When the user enters the 4th digit of the PIN, the screen will automatically change this text to **Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm**. When the screen changes here, I want to compare both PINs to check if they are the same or not. And show text here if PIN is not same.

Remember that I am using the same PinFieldAutoFill widget. Based on this, I want to set and confirm the PIN.

**Screen for Set Pin**

[image]

**Screen for Re-enter Pin**

[image]

How can I do it?

Here is my SetPinTestscreen:

```
class _SetPinTestscreenState extends State<SetPinTestscreen> {
  TextEditingController setPinController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void initState() {
    Provider.of<PinValidationProvider>(context, listen: false).isPinSet = false;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MainTemplate(
      isFloatingButtonVisible: true,
      floatingButtonAction: () {},
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
                builder: (context, pinProvider, child) {
                  return Text(
                    pinProvider.isPinSet
                        ? 'Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm'
                        : 'Set PIN for your Card Ending With XXXX',
                    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w700, fontSize: 30),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Center(
              child: PinFieldAutoFill(
                decoration: UnderlineDecoration(
                  textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.subtitle1.copyWith(
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        fontSize: 15,
                      ),
                  gapSpace: 8,
                  lineHeight: 1.2,
                  colorBuilder:
                      PinListenColorBuilder(Colors.black, Colors.grey.shade400),
                ),
                onCodeChanged: (value) {
                  Provider.of<PinValidationProvider>(context, listen: false)
                      .validatePin(value, setPinController);
                },
                codeLength: 4,
                cursor: Cursor(color: Colors.black, enabled: true),
                controller: setPinController,
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Consumer<PinValidationProvider>(
                builder: (context, provider, child) {
              final textColor =
                  provider.isInvalidPin ? Colors.red : Colors.black;

              return provider.isPinSet
                  ? SizedBox.shrink()
                  : Text(
                      'Pin must be at least 4 digits. It must not be single digits like'
                      ' 1111 or digits in numerical order such as 1234',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: textColor,
                      ),
                    );
            }),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is my PinValidationProvider class

```
class PinValidationProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool _isInvalidPin = false;

  bool get isInvalidPin => _isInvalidPin;
  bool isPinSet = false;
  String pin = '';
  String confirmedPin = '';

  void validatePin(String pin,TextEditingController controller) {
    if (pin.length != 4) {
      _isInvalidPin = false;
      pin = pin ?? '';
    } else {
      confirmedPin = pin ?? '';
      controller.clear();
      if (_isSimpleSequence(pin) || _isRepeatedDigit(pin)) {
        _isInvalidPin = true;
      } else {
        _isInvalidPin = false;
        if (!isPinSet) {
          isPinSet = true;
        }
      }
    }
    Future.microtask(() {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  bool _isSimpleSequence(String pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.length - 1; i++) {
      int digit1 = int.parse(pin[i]);
      int digit2 = int.parse(pin[i + 1]);

      if (digit2 - digit1 == 1) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }

  bool _isRepeatedDigit(String pin) {
    for (int i = 0; i < pin.length - 1; i++) {
      if (pin[i] == pin[i + 1]) {
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See you do have the boolean check that tells you that you're on which state **Set PIN for your Card Ending With XXXX** or **Re-enter your PIN code to Confirm**. And you do have the variables for pin and confirmedPin in the provider.

So you need to do is if `!pinProvider.isPinSet` means **Set PIN for your Card Ending With XXXX** screen you need to save the user entered pin in the pin and otherwise save it in the confirmedPin and after the confirmedPin reaches length of 4 then call your provider's `validatePin` function and check both of them. and do certain actions accordingly.

This whole this you need to do in the `onCodeChanged` of `PinFieldAutoFill`.

See it would be like this for onCodeChanged..

```
onCodeChanged: (value) {
   if (pinProvider.isPinSet) {
      pinProvider.confirmedPin = value;
      if (value.length == 4) {
         pinProvider.validatePin();
      }
   } else {
      pinProvider.pin = value;
   }
},
```

And for validatePin function it would be kind of like this.

```
  void validatePin() {
    if (pin != null &&
        confirmedPin != null &&
        pin.length == 4 &&
        confirmedPin == 4) {
      if (pin == confirmedPin) {
        /// do certain actions if the [Pins] are same.
      } else {
        /// do certain actions if the [Pins] are different.
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: kindly give me the snippet of code. it'll be better for me. Thanks.

Comment: see i have add some code to give you the idea.

Comment: please accept the answer if it solved or helped you to solve your problem.

Comment: bro i resolved this issue already. Kindly help me on that other question

Comment: I will accept this also for you , just kindly help me on that question

Comment: i have posted answer for that, have you tried that!?

Comment: Kindly can you give me the code how to resolve that issue.

Comment: man! why you delete the post? i was stuck with something and now got time to try.